# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest callback's parameter details.initiator is only a origin ,how to find the specific URL?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, browser, adblock

for example:
how blocking 'bar.com/ad.js','barxxx.com/adxxx.js' in the tab 'foo.com/'.
dont blocking 'bar.com/ad.js','barxxx.com/adxxx.js' in the tab 'foo.com/09'

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  callback: function,
  filter: RequestFilter,
  extraInfoSpec?: OnBeforeRequestOptions[],
)
```

[callback function' Object parameter has a property: 'initiator'](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRequest)

*initiator*
*string optional*

*Chrome 63+*
*The origin where the request was initiated. This does not change through redirects. If this is an opaque origin, the string 'null' will be used.*

Comment: You'll have to accumulate the `url`  yourself in a global object where tabId is the key and frameId is the sub-key in the inner object. Then you'll use it as `urls[info.tabId]?.[info.frameId]`